# Issue on chrome with label:hover and relative positioning

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover, positioning, css-position

For part of a site I'm working on, I am constructing a price list... Since it is to be interactive, I am using checkbox type inputs and labels to make this; you check which services you want and the webpage gives you the total cost of these services.  Easy enough.

My problem is a stylistic one; I am using a span with the float property set to right to distinguish between the price and the service description(the price gets right aligned within a div, the description gets left aligned next to the check box).  The entire label is positioned with relative positioning.  When I set the hover pseudo class to change the color of the label, the color change doesn't seem to work properly on chrome.  Below is a small code sample that replicates the issue...

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        div#leftcolumn
        {
            width:500px;
        }
        span.right
        {
            float:right;
        }
        input, label
        {
            position:relative;
            left:50px;
        }
        label:hover
        {
            color:#FF0000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="leftcolumn">
        <input id="option1" type="checkbox" /><label for="option1">This is a label... span class="right">and this is the same label</span></label><br/>
        <input id="option2" type="checkbox" /><label for="option2">A new label!<span class="right">Y U NO COLOR RIGHT</span></label>
    </div>
</body>
```

If you try this example on Chrome, I believe you should notice very odd hover behavior...  However, this seems to work fine in Firefox and Internet explorer.  Is this a bug with chrome?  Is this poor coding on my part?  My actual page validates....  I would appreciate it if someone who understands this problem would explain what is going on.  I know I can make a work-around by moving the relative positioning into a div and placing all my inputs and labels in that div instead of positioning the labels and inputs directly, but I feel as though this SHOULD work....

As always, thank you for your time.

Comment: I should emphasize that as I said in my question, I can get a work-around by throwing in one more div, and moving the positioning into that div instead of directly on the input and label.  My main question here is WHY does this happen?  Is there some part of my code using poor design practice, or is this just a chrome thing?  If it is a chrome issue, should I file a bug report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not with label position:relative; 
It seems your problem with float:right

I recommend you to replace span.right with this style

```
    span.right
    {
        padding-left:100px;
    }
```

another way to solve this issue is to add clear:right; to label:hover style

```
    label:hover
    {
        color:#FF0000; clear:right;
    }
```

Comment: It seems you are right that replacing float:right will get rid of the weird coloring on Chrome, however setting padding-left does not right align the text as I would like(and in application, I will have many more than 2 inputs).  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I found a great solution for you without replacing span.right style, just add clear:right; to label:hover style. It will be like this         label:hover { color:#FF0000; clear:right; }

Comment: That is a great solution!  I've never used the clear property before, looks like I have some reading to do...  This does fix the issue without throwing in a lot of extra div tags.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following:

```
span.right
{
position:relative;
left:150px;
}
```

I believe this is the effect you are looking for.

Comment: As with Abood's answer, this does indeed fix the color issue, at the expense of not being able right-align the text.  I've tried throwing a text-align:right; into the span, but this doesn't work on a label.  Thank you for your answer.